# Триггер с передачей инициатора эвента .... jquery

Tags: jquery

Хочу вызвать триггер кликом, чтобы this из другой функции подхватил кликнутый элемент. Мой код получает ошибку на slice, что значение не определено.

```
$(document).on('click','.inventory_item_link', function clickbuttonadditem(event){
    $('.inventory_item_link').trigger('selectitem',[event]);
});

$(document).bind('selectitem', function selectitem(event, iditem){
    iditem = $(this).attr('href').slice(1,4);
    console.log('selectitem '+iditem);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо передать элемент this внутрь функции,
следующий код работает без ошибки:

```
$(document).on('click','.inventory_item_link', function clickbuttonadditem(event){
    $('.inventory_item_link').trigger('selectitem',[this, event]);
    return false;
});

$(document).bind('selectitem', function selectitem(event, el, iditem){
    iditem = $(el).attr('href').slice(1,4);
    console.log('selectitem '+iditem);
});
```

Comment: Можете объяснить логику того что вы изменили и добавили?

Comment: Это довольно обширная тема, в первую очередь необходимо понимать как определяется this и чему он равен в зависимости от контекста. Об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149516/)

Comment: 1. Я добавил this при вызове триггера, это передаст ссылку на элемент у которого было вызвано событие. 2. В функции selectitem принял этот параметр в переменную el. 3.  В теле функции selectitem заменил this на  el

Comment: А почему переменная el приняла его, а не любая другая из в функции?

Comment: Такая сигнатура у метода bind, первым входящим параметром всегда идёт event, затем параметры в том порядке которые были переданы. В коде передаются параметры [this, event], соответственно функция их примет в el, iditem.

Comment: Код выполняется два раза(логируется) и в другой код я его не оборачивал, что не так?

Comment: Я понял, this берет все элементы с классом .inventory_item_link, не только кликнутый. Как бы этот косяк исправить?

Comment: Попробуй вместо $('.inventory_item_link').trigger, использовать $(this).trigger

Comment: Я уже решил, document в селектор написал, там где класс.